# How to start dynamics at different time points?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, time-series

I have a 2D system of equations `dR` and `dC`. I compute the time-series trajectory for it as shown below. However, I want to start them at different time points. For instance, in `R` starts at 0, I want to start `C` at 20. Important: I need `C` to start from the same initial condition of 1.75 when it starts at 20. So I am not looking for simple manipulation of the time range. Any suggestions on how to go about this?

```
dRnum = r'[t] == u*r[t] - f*r[t]*c[t]
dCnum = c'[t] == e*f*r[t]*c[t] - d*c[t]

Pars = {u -> 1, f -> 0.5, e -> 0.7, d -> 0.2};

LVsolve1 = 
  NDSolve[{dRnum /. Pars, dCnum /. Pars, r[0] == 0.75, 
    c[0] == 1.75}, {r[t], c[t]}, {t, 0, 100}];

PlotLVTime1 = 
 Plot[Evaluate[{r[t], c[t]} /. LVsolve1], {t, 0, 100}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 4}}, PlotStyle -> {Green, Blue}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"t", "R and C"}]
```

[image]

Comment: You did not define Pars

Comment: @DanielHuber Thank you for pointing it out. I have defined it now.

Comment: Do you want `r[0] == 0.75, c[20] == 1.75`? If so, did you try that?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to start the dynamics at different points in time?
As that can be achieved using [`Boole`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Boole.html):

```
dRnum = r'[t] == u*r[t] - f*r[t]*c[t]
dCnum = c'[t] == Boole[t >= 20]*(e*f*r[t]*c[t] - d*c[t]) + Boole[t < 20]* 0

Pars = {u -> 1, f -> 0.5, e -> 0.7, d -> 0.2};

LVsolve1 = 
  NDSolve[{dRnum /. Pars, dCnum /. Pars, r[0] == 0.75, 
    c[0] == 1.75}, {r[t], c[t]}, {t, 0, 100}];

LVsolve2 = 
  NDSolve[{dRnum /. Pars, dCnum /. Pars, r[0] == 1.25, 
    c[0] == 1}, {r[t], c[t]}, {t, 0, 100}];

PlotLVTime1 = 
 Plot[Evaluate[{r[t], c[t]} /. LVsolve1], {t, 0, 100}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, Automatic}, PlotStyle -> {Green, Blue}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"t", "R and C"}]
```

[image]

Comment: @Biotechgeek Is this what you want? Maybe `c[t]` should not be part of the differential equations for `r'[t]` before `t = 20`? (But then you should express yourself a bit more clearly...)

Answer (score 0):

You can make 2 different plots and combine them using Show:

```
Show[
 Plot[Evaluate[r[t] /. LVsolve1], {t, 0, 100}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, 4}}, PlotStyle -> Green, 
  AxesLabel -> {"t", "R and C"}],
 Plot[Evaluate[c[t] /. LVsolve1], {t, 20, 100}, PlotStyle -> Blue]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm..but I want to start the dynamic from the same initial starting condition but at time point 20.  Apologies is it wasn't clear from the question. I'll change it up now